# How can I get a file.class from a directory(for example desktop) and use it as an Object?

Tags: testing, junit

Hi I want to be able to run a JunitTest Class that is not inside my eclipse project,but in a directory , thats is what I mean

```
Class<?> clazz = How can I get a file.class("my/dir");
Result result =  JUnitCore.runClasses(clazz);
for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
     System.out.println(failure.toString());
}
System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
}
```

Comment: You have one extra `}`

Comment: Use regular file reader Java (API)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html]

Comment: I can't see this link can you retype it?

Comment: This comment show how to read a file http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/1371064 .

Comment: @αƞjiβ I can't see this link can you retype it?

Comment: @CarlosAndresGarcía thank you very userfull 
now that I have the inputStream I want to be able to convert this and put it in a (for example)
Class<?> clazz = inputStream.class
and try to put it in 
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(clazz);
because JUnitcore runnerClasse requires a .class type
I tried to do inputStream.getClass but it returns the class of input Stream not the Class get from the input directory
sorry if it isnt so clear